# fatal error after installation

Tags: wamp, fatal-error

I am using wamp and installed open fit (http://www.openfitapi.com/documentation/install/openfit-web).

After installing open fit, I get this fatal error message when I try to visit the localhost daskboard page....

> Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in C:\wamp\www\openfit7.x1.1\sites\all\modules\openfit_api\openfit_api.Measurement.inc
> on line 188

Also after directly installing I got other error messages....

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 2102 in search_simplify()
> (line 445 of
> C:\wamp\www\openfit-7.x-1.1\modules\search\search.module).
>
> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
> 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
> ini_set() in DefaultMailSystem->mail() (line 76 of
> C:\wamp\www\openfit-7.x-1.1\modules\system\system.mail.inc).

Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a fairly well known issue.

The way to solve it seems to be

1. Make sure you have PHP5.3 installed ( not sure if this is a minimum requirement or that it has to be 5.3)
2. Make sure you have the php_intl extension enabled.

Look here [The Openfit site](http://openfitapi.com/taxonomy/term/5), found with a google search *openfit "Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found"*

Comment: Do you think it matters if I am using a 64 bit mackine?

Comment: You need to check the requirements for openfit. It looks like it may be a library that has not been recently maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You might try installing a vanilla Drupal.  During that process, there is a verification page where Drupal checks that you have all the necessary libs in place.  It's a shot in the dark, but it might point out something significant.

BTW, I came across this post because I was researching openfit.  The download links are dead when I click them.  How did you get a hold of it?  Could you send me the zip? cmatser 'at' codespinnerinc.com THANKS!

Comment: Is your email "cmaster" or "cmatser" ? I sent to cmaster and it was not deliverable.

Comment: im sending right after this post. Question:I installed easy php and did not get the error but now I have a new one. "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\openfit-7.x-1.1\includes\database\database.inc on line 2135"

Comment: If the licence permits it (FOSS or something), can you – or someone else who has the source code – make it available? Upload it somewhere?